# Telegram server close connection

Tags: c#, api, telegram

I'm coding a C# client for telegram, I'm using async sockets to receive updates from telegram server leveraging the BeginReceive methods.
The problem is that after some days the EndReceive methods starts to read 0 bytes, probably because the telegram server close my connection.

Is there any method to avoid this leveraging the telegram API? I've tried with a ping every 5 mnutes but seems that it isn't enough to keep the connection up with the server.

Comment: _"after some days"_ - does it hurt to reconnect every couple of days? Anyway see duplicate: the server or any device in between can decide to close the connection for whatever reason, and you have no influence on this from the client side in any way whatsoever. Prepare your code so it can reconnect.

Comment: It is exactly what I've done: reconnect to the telegram server when bytesRead == 0. It seems that it is the right way to do this according also with the answer you have suggested.

Comment: Yes, it is! Getting 0 returned from `recv()` means the other end has gracefully closed the connection. If you wish to communicate further, you must open a new connection.

Comment: yes, obviously re-using the same session since I don't want the user to authenticate again the client. Thanks! :-)